# Curl command to push a war file to url in github actions

Tags: url, curl, github-actions

So I'm having in issue where I want this maven installed war file to be named artifactId##version.war in a curl commands url; in the curl command I tried putting in \ and %23 but both instances I get this message *The Path is not formatted correctly - must begin with '/repositories//...'* and when its just the name artifactId##version  when it pushes or uploads it to the website I want it only names it artifactId and leaves out the rest, the problem isn't in getting the artifactID name or version number or the maven install it's in the curl command portion of the code and the reason why I have two FILE_TO_UPLOAD is because of one is the file name installed and another is whats gonna be the name uploaded and like I said if I just put ## it'll just upload the artifactId

```
      run:|
           mvn install     
           #CODE WHERE THE PROBLEM IS                                                                       
           FILE_TO_UPLOAD="ARTIFACTID\#\#VERSION.war" 
           FILE_TO_UPLOAD2="ARTIFACTID##VERSION.war" 
           echo ${FILE_TO_UPLOAD} #for testing
           TARGET_URL=https://example.com/PATH/${FILE_TO_UPLOAD}          
           curl -u 'username:password' --upload-file ${FILE_TO_UPLOAD2} ${TARGET_URL}
           #CODE WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
```